# UITableViewCell unwanted content offset

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

For some reason the cell contents are displayed below the actual cell.

[image]

What could be going on? Here is the code:

```
cell!.nameLabel!.text = name
cell!.imageView!.image = decodedimage
return cell!;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all cells are of the same height you can simply put

```
   self.tableView.rowHeight = 66  // or whatever
```

in the `viewDidLoad()` of your tableViewController class.

If the cell heights vary depending on their content you should consider to override `tableView.heightForRowAtIndexPath()`

Comment: That seems to cause the problem. When I take it out it works just fine, just that the height is then huge and only fits 3 rows on the screen